# UserTransaction.rollback exception HHH000451

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I am trying to implement a two phase atomic commit or rollback pattern. The steps are:

1. read database and populate a ui form
2. enter changes in the form submit for update and application level validate
3. do one of two actions

   a. commit the multiple changes in one transaction 
   b. rollback the multiple changes to discard

These steps when done with a commit action work well, database read, form populated and updated, changes update the database.

When these steps are done with a rollback action, the behaviour is identical except an exception is thrown at userTransaction.rollback()

[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl] (default task-30) HHH000451: 
  Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it.
  [status=4]
  (default task-30) sessionAbort ex org.hibernate.HibernateException: Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!

Why don't I get an exception thrown when I commit? Each submit of the form has its own thread, but I don't see a multithread issue. I am not sure where to focus my investigation next. MySql or Wildfly or JPA/Hibernate?

Versions are:

- java version "1.7.0_07"
- ejb3
- wildfly-8.2.0.Final
- mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.5.21, for Linux on x86_64
- RichFaces 4.5.4
- Using dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Sudo code is:

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@Stateful(mappedName = "testSession")
@SessionScoped
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class TestSession {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="MySqlXA",type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)    
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Resource private UserTransaction userTransaction;

First request/ thread one

    userTransaction.begin();    
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sqlQuery);
    List<SomeTable> queryResult = (List<SomeTable>)query.getResultList();
    populate a SessionScoped ManagedBean

    user think time
    make updates through the UI and submit

Second request / thread two

   TableOneRow tableOneRow = new TableOneRow(someStuff);
   TableTwoRow tableTwoRow = entityManager.find(otherStuff);

    entityManager.persist(tableOneRow);
    entitymanager.merge(tableTwoRow);

Third request / thread three submit for commit

   userTransaction.commit();

or Third request / thread three submit for abort

   userTransaction.rollback();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With further research and experimentation, it looks like the cleanest way to discard a set of updates is to call entityManager.clear().

See below for a log of three tests and the relevant code. The first group of find,update,commit is my baseline of a good update. The second group of find,update,abort results in the HHH000451 exception. The last bit is the abort portion but using EntityManager clear instead.

```
2017-03-23 16:48:55,425 DEBUG [view.TestPage] (default task-21) find
2017-03-23 16:48:55,426 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-21) findNameAddress for addrId 5
2017-03-23 16:48:55,426 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-21) entityManager.find
2017-03-23 16:48:55,465 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-21) findNameAddress success true

2017-03-23 16:49:49,714 DEBUG [view.TestPage] (default task-24) update
2017-03-23 16:49:49,714 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-24) updateFirstLastName to One, For
2017-03-23 16:49:49,715 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-24) userTransaction.begin
2017-03-23 16:49:49,716 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-24) userTransaction.begin success true
2017-03-23 16:49:49,716 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-24) findNameAddress for addrId 5
2017-03-23 16:49:49,716 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-24) entityManager.find
2017-03-23 16:49:49,716 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-24) findNameAddress success true
2017-03-23 16:49:49,716 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-24) entityManager.merge
2017-03-23 16:49:49,721 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-24) updateFirstLastName success true

2017-03-23 16:50:19,652 DEBUG [view.TestPage] (default task-25) commit
2017-03-23 16:50:19,654 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-25) userTransaction.commit
2017-03-23 16:50:19,726 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-25) userTransaction.commit success true

2017-03-23 16:50:50,740 DEBUG [view.TestPage] (default task-26) find
2017-03-23 16:50:50,741 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-26) findNameAddress for addrId 5
2017-03-23 16:50:50,741 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-26) entityManager.find
2017-03-23 16:50:50,741 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-26) findNameAddress success true

2017-03-23 16:51:12,735 DEBUG [view.TestPage] (default task-29) update
2017-03-23 16:51:12,735 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-29) updateFirstLastName to two, For
2017-03-23 16:51:12,735 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-29) userTransaction.begin
2017-03-23 16:51:12,736 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-29) userTransaction.begin success true
2017-03-23 16:51:12,736 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-29) findNameAddress for addrId 5
2017-03-23 16:51:12,736 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-29) entityManager.find
2017-03-23 16:51:12,736 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-29) findNameAddress success true
2017-03-23 16:51:12,736 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-29) entityManager.merge
2017-03-23 16:51:12,736 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-29) updateFirstLastName success true

2017-03-23 16:51:40,888 DEBUG [view.TestPage] (default task-30) abort
2017-03-23 16:51:40,889 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-30) userTransaction.rollback
2017-03-23 16:51:40,890 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl] (default task-30) HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
2017-03-23 16:51:40,891 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-30) userTransaction.rollback success true



2017-03-23 16:54:08,623 DEBUG [view.TestPage] (default task-12) abort
2017-03-23 16:54:08,624 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-12) entityManager.clear
2017-03-23 16:54:08,625 TRACE [ejb.session.TestPageSession] (default task-12) entityManager.clear success true

package com.gregdata.session;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import com.gregdata.model.Nameaddress;

@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@Stateful(mappedName = "localTestSession")
@SessionScoped
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class TestPageSession implements TestPageSessionLocal {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="MySqlStocksXA",
                    type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)   
private EntityManager entityManager;
@Resource private UserTransaction userTransaction;

private Nameaddress nameaddress;
private boolean transactionBegun;

private Logger logger;

public TestPageSession() {
    logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
}

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {      
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public Nameaddress findNameaddress(int addrId)
{
    Nameaddress nameaddress = null;
    boolean success = false;

    logger.trace("findNameAddress for addrId "+addrId);

    try {
        logger.trace("entityManager.find");
        nameaddress = entityManager.find(Nameaddress.class, addrId);
        success = true;
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.warn("findNameAddress ex: "+ex.getMessage());
        success = true;
    }

    logger.trace("findNameAddress success "+success);

    return nameaddress;
}

public boolean updateFirstLastName(int addrId, String firstName, String lastName)
{
    boolean success = false;

    logger.trace("updateFirstLastName to "+firstName+", "+lastName);

    try
    {
        beginTransaction();

        nameaddress = findNameaddress(addrId);
        if ( nameaddress == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Nameaddress id "+addrId+" not found");
        }

        nameaddress.setFirstName(firstName);
        nameaddress.setLastName(lastName);
        logger.trace("entityManager.merge");
        entityManager.merge(nameaddress);

        success = true;

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.warn("updateFirstLastName ex: "+ex.getMessage());
        success = false;            
    }

    logger.trace("updateFirstLastName success "+success);

    return success;

}

public boolean beginTransaction()
{

    boolean success = false;

    if (transactionBegun) return true;

    logger.trace("userTransaction.begin");

    try
    {
        userTransaction.begin();
        success = true;
        transactionBegun = true;        
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.warn("userTransaction.begin ex "+ex.getMessage());
        success = false;        
    }

    logger.trace("userTransaction.begin success "+success);

    return success;
}

public boolean commitTransaction()
{
    boolean success = false;

    logger.trace("userTransaction.commit");

    try
    {           
        userTransaction.commit();           
        success = true;
        transactionBegun = false;
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.warn("userTransaction.commit ex "+ex.getMessage());
        success = false;
        transactionBegun = false;
    }
    logger.trace("userTransaction.commit success "+success);

    return success;
}

public boolean abortTransaction()
{
    boolean success = false;

    logger.trace("userTransaction.rollback");

    try
    {
        userTransaction.rollback();
        success = true;
        transactionBegun = false;
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.warn("userTransaction.rollback ex "+ex.getMessage());
        transactionBegun = false;
        success = false;
    }

    logger.trace("userTransaction.rollback success "+success);
    return success;     
}

public boolean clearEntityManager() {

    boolean success = false;

    logger.trace("entityManager.clear");

    try {
        entityManager.clear();
        success = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.warn("clearEntityManager ex: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
    logger.trace("entityManager.clear success "+success);

    return success;
}
}
```